# Chef server on AWS t2 micro memory issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I am using AWS to install chef server 12 on EC2 T2 micro. I have downloaded the 64-bit deb package version, which is applicable.

I have setup the following on the box:

1. hosts file added:
   a. added ec2 ip to ec2 public dns name
2. installed and started ntp daemon

I am getting a a few errors but the "main" one is listed below listed below:

1. Main issue here is a memory issue:

   **Errno::ENOMEM**

   **-------------**

   **Cannot allocate memory - fork(2)**

`================================================================================
    Error executing action`run` on resource 'execute[restart_rabbitmq_log_service]'
    ================================================================================

```
Errno::ENOMEM
-------------
Cannot allocate memory - fork(2)

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/cookbooks/enterprise/definitions/component_runit_service.rb

 19:   execute "restart_#{component}_log_service" do
 20:     command "#{node['runit']['sv_bin']} restart #{node['runit']['sv_dir']}/#{component}/log"
 21:     action :nothing
 22:   end
 23:
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you really need at least 4GB of RAM for a Chef Server. https://docs.chef.io/chef_system_requirements.html#the-chef-server has the formal docs which say 8GB but 4GB plus some swap would probably not run too poorly.

Comment: Checked the docs, but wanted confirmation. :thumbsup: I will try to utilize swap to displace the missy ram space. Once i test it I will mark this as solved if it works, just wanted confirmation.

Comment: It will get very very slow. Solr uses a lot of heap space.